# Put pdf files in subfolder

Tags: javascript, pdf, acrobat

I have a acrobat javascript that produces single page pdf files from a multipage pdf file, however I want it it put the output files in a subfolder named single, I cant get it to work, here is my code:

```
/* Extract Pages to Folder */


var re = /.*\/|\.pdf$/ig;

var filename = this.path.replace(re,"");

{
    for ( var i = 0;  i < this.numPages; i++ )
    this.extractPages
     ({
        nStart: i,
        cPath : Number(filename) + (i+1) + ".pdf"
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to set cPath to the fully qualified path you want the file to be saved to. However, in my experience, the subfolder needs to exist first.

Comment: You r absolutely right! I noticed this, I thik I have to run the Script from outside of Acrobat fpr it to be able to create the folder. Also I need to combine it with another script I have that takes the single side pdfs into photoshop and outputs thumbnails and images. I am looking into Adobe extended scripting. Thank you for yoir answer!